# AutoHotKey command to fix issue witih Visual Studio and Global Shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

I love keyboard shortcuts, and I've recently grown to love an app that I use called "Switcher." (http://insentient.net/)  It's basically a fast, expose type alt-tab replacement for Windows.  The problem is that it doesn't respond to the keyboard shortcut when I'm in Visual Studio or SQL Server Management studio (two apps I live in every day).  As soon as I unfocus VS or SSMS, I can use the alt-~ or whatever other shortcut I've set.  Even the mouse gesture feature of switcher didn't work.

I'm hoping that there's an autohotkey script that can help me get get around this by routing my alt-tab or alt-~ to a different window even when I'm in VS/SSMS so that I can get my switcher to work correctly.

Any AHK experts out there got any advice?

Comment: Is the problem that VS and/or SSMS have this key combination mapped to something else? Do you use ReSharper? By default, I think ReSharper uses Alt+` for "Navigate To". If this is the case, just removing the mapping in VS should allow your switcher to work as expected.

Comment: I am using ReSharper, and I thought that was the case, but ReSharper doesn't affect SSMS...it might have the key mapped to something though.  I haven't been able to find it out  yet.  The workaround was to map switcher to alt-tab and then hit alt-tab twice...once to get out of SSMS/VS, and then once to activate switcher...I'll continue to see if I can dig up what keys are mapped...

Answer (score 2):

In Autohotkey_L I have my 4th mouse button (XButton1) mapped to pull up Switcher.  Switcher is set to activate on `` Windows Key + ` ``.  This works for me even when Visual Studio is active.

Here is the code:

```
; Trigger Switcher
XButton1::Send, {LWin Down}``{LWin Up}
```

Because the backquote (`) character is an escape character for Autohotkey, you will need to type it twice so that it resolves to the so called tilde (~) key on the keyboard.  If that doesn't resolve your issue, then post your code and I may be able to provide further help.